# Why console don't show methods of jQuery object returned from selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, console, google-chrome-devtools

I know that if I type:

> $('body');

I get a jQuery object. However on chrome's console I'll only see the internal array of the jQuery object, despite the fact that jQuery methods are accessible like

> $('body').hide();

Why the console don't show me all the accessible methods and how did jQuery manage to do this magic?

If it's just because these methods are defined on a prototype, then how come when I write these lines:

```
function Person(){this.myProp = 'test'};
var person = new Person();
Person.prototype.proto = 'test2';
```

and then I inspect person in chrome I will see:

`__proto__: Person
constructor: Person()
proto: "test2"`

but when Inspecting `$('body');` then no **proto** is shown on dev tools?

Comment: The jQuery methods are on the **prototype**, not each individual object.

Comment: `$('body')` returns an object which inherits from  `$.fn`. If you inspect it with the console, you will see an entry called `__proto__` or `[[Prototype]]` or something like that.

Comment: @Oriol - Actually I was looking for something like this, but try it yourself - $('body') only returns the array. Chrome doesn't show anything else except that?

Comment: @BornToCode They messed up Chrome's console. Better use Firefox's one. `$('body')` returns an array-like object which is not an array, and which inherits from `$.fn` via internal [[Prototype]]. Edit: use `console.log($('body'))` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The methods are on the prototype of the object.  Both the console and `console.log()` do not, by default, show items on the prototype.

If you examine a jQuery object in the Chrome debugger, you can expand the prototype and can then see all the methods there.

So, what you are seeing is just the chosen implementation of the console.  It shows direct instance properties, not items on the prototype.

---

When I put this code into a page:

```
function Person(){this.myProp = 'test'};
Person.prototype.proto = 'test2';

var person = new Person();
var jq = $("body");
```

And, then examine both `person` and `jq` in the Chrome debugger, I see this:

[image]

which shows the `**proto** property on both objects.  And, if I expand that property for the jQuery object, it does indeed show all the methods.

Comment: +1 However when I expand my own object with a prototype I do see a `__proto__` attribute, which is not present on jQuery objects for some reason? (see my edit for an example)

Comment: @BornToCode - see what I added to my answer.

Comment: Chrome's debugger indeed shows the proto that wasn't visible on Chrome's console on the jQuery object; I'm accepting your answer.